# What is the literal meaning of the scientific name for the cactus wren?

Tags: zoology, nomenclature, etymology

What does the scientific name *Campylorhynchus brunneicapillum* mean? I simply want to find a way to decipher the meaning of scientific names. In the past I had to translate the names syllable by syllable using an abbreviated Latin dictionary to get a rough idea of the meaning. I can not find an on-line Latin translator that works - and not all scientific names are Latin.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Helm Dictionary of Scientific Bird Names](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-RfSBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false):

- *Kampylos*, καμπúλος (Greek): curved, bent;
- *Rhynchos*, ῥύγχος (Greek): bill.

Also, for the specific epithet:

- *Brunneus* (late Latin): brown;
- *Capillus* (Latin): hair.

Page with the Genus name: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-RfSBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false

Page with the specific epithet: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-RfSBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA78#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: PS: I already knew this by heart because I studied Ancient Greek (and Latin is quite obvious to me because I speak a Romanic language), but I linked that "birds names dictionary" so you can have another source to search. Also, have in mind that it's complicated to use a regular Latin or Greek dictionary as you use an English one because you have to know the declension and the nominative form of the word. For instance, *androgen*: if you look for *andros* in a Greek dictionary you're not gonna find it, because that's the genitive. You have to look for *aner*, which is the nominative.